# I need the boost::mpl implementation of exp() function

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

Does anybody know where can I find it? Otherwise I'll have to write it by myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Milwaukee Public Library ? Mars Polar Lander ? Messenger Plus! Live ? Monthly Purchase Limit ?

Comment: Mozilla Public Licence? boost::mpl?

Comment: @David Heffernan: yes, boost::mpl

Comment: @niXman If it's boost, then why don't you just download it?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Do you know the exp() function?
I need the mpl implementation of this function.
I use boost anyway. I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: @niXman You mean exp(), the inverse of log() or exponentiation to the power e, the natural number. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exp function in [boost::mpl 1.45](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html). I've [counted them](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/refmanual_toc.html). [Twice](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/boost/mpl/arithmetic.hpp).

Perhaps you could create your own by applying the [times](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/times.html) meta-function recursively.

Comment: спасибо.
я говорю на русском. посему, мне сложно излагать на английском.
вопрос заключался в том, где можно найти готовую реализацию метафункции exp().
придется писать самому.

Comment: "Thanks. I speak Russian. Therefore, I find it difficult to express in English. question was, where you can find a ready implementation metafunction exp (). have to write myself"

Comment: @niXman If you are dealing with integral powers of e, then you can create one easily using the recursive relationships - exp(2N) = exp(N)**2; exp(N+1) = e * exp(N), exp(0) = 1. I'm not sure how you would deal with fractional powers without converting a full implementation of exp() such as http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_exp.c to a template meta-function.